# can i get Easy code to send data to lcd can i get Easy code to send data to lcd

Tags: stm32

it's my code I want to make this code shorter.
How can I shorten the 8bit data transfer code?

```
    void LCD_Cmd(uint8_t cmd) {
    /* Command mode */
    GPIOC->BRR =((uint16_t)0x8000U); // RS LOW
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_15, (cmd & 0x01));
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_0, (cmd & 0x02));
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_1, (cmd & 0x04));
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_3, (cmd & 0x08));
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_4, (cmd & 0x10));
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_5, (cmd & 0x20));
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_6, (cmd & 0x40));
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_7, (cmd & 0x80));
    GPIOC->BSRR =((uint16_t)0x4000U); // E SET
    HAL_Delay(1);
    GPIOC->BRR = ((uint16_t)0x4000U); // E RESET
```

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your goal and what blockers did you meet?

Answer (score 1):

You could just skip the whole HAL_GPIO_WritePin to write directly to the output register as you have most of your gpio on the same port but you still nedd to adjust your cmd bit ordering to fit your wiring so if it is possible it should be better to rewire the lcd to reflect your configuration.

```
if (cmd & 1)
  GPIOA->ODR |= 0x80;
else 
  GPIOA->ODR &= 0x7F);
GPIOB->ODR |= (adjusted_cmd & 0xfb);
GPIOB->ODR &= ~(adjusted_cmd & 0xfb);
```

Comment: What is adjusted_cmd

Comment: Is cmd value adjusted so bits fits the GPIOB port output bits. 
7654 3x21

Comment: Should I show you how to use masks and shifts? I think that's OT. You can search for it yourself, there's planty of informations about.

Answer (score 0):

1. DO NOT USE HAL_... and HAL_Delay. Setting the pin this way takes ages. You need `ns` or `us`for the delay and you have minimum of 2ms here.

Setting the bits in the `GPIOA` `GPIOB` fastest way in this case

```
void foo3(unsigned cmd)
{
    if(cmd &1) GPIOA -> BSRR = 1;
    else GPIOA -> BSRR = 1 << 16;
    unsigned tmp = (cmd >> 1);
    tmp &= ~0b11111100;
    tmp |= cmd & 0b11111100;
    tmp &= ~(1 << 2);
    GPIOB -> BSRR = tmp; 
    tmp = ~tmp;
    tmp &= ~(1 << 2);
    GPIOB -> BRR = tmp; 
}

//and this code compiles to 16 assembly instructions
// without any branches

        tst     r0, #1
        mov     r3, #67108864
        movne   r2, #1
        moveq   r2, #65536
        str     r2, [r3, #8]
        lsr     r3, r0, #1
        bic     r3, r3, #252
        and     r0, r0, #252
        orr     r0, r0, r3
        mvn     r3, r0
        ldr     r2, .L5
        bic     r3, r3, #4
        bic     r0, r0, #4
        str     r0, [r2, #8]
        str     r3, [r2, #4]
        bx      lr
```

Comment: You missed the fact that cmd bits after bit2 doesn't have to be shifted left.

Comment: @Damiano your comment is outdated